# TikZ: How to define a node with a custom inner sep on one side (e.g. on the right side of an rectangle)?

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following MWE constructs some kind of custom node (combination of two nodes) to get the desired result:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    every node/.style={fill=blue!30,draw,rectangle,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt},
    innerRectangle/.style={minimum height=2cm, minimum width=2cm},
    outerRectangle/.style={fill=red!50,minimum height=3cm, minimum width=2.5cm},
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[outerRectangle] (o) {};
        \node[innerRectangle,anchor=east] (i) at (o.east) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]

Question: Is there an easier way, e.g. a single node definition with custom inner seps for one or each side?

**Update 1** (triggered by Ignasi's answer):

I did not mention that I would like to insert text into the inner node and that this text should honor the custom inner sep. The following MWE (based on Ignasi's answer, I just added the `lipsum` package and replaced `minimum width` by `text width`) demonstrates the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzset{
    every node/.style={
        fill=blue!30,
        draw,
        rectangle,
        inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt
    },
    outerRectangle/.style={%
        fill=red!50,
        minimum height=3cm,
        text width=5cm,
    },%
    innerRectangle/.style={%
        path picture={%
            \draw[fill=blue!30] ([yshift=-#1]path picture bounding box.north east)
                -|([xshift=#1]path picture bounding box.west)
               |-([yshift=#1]path picture bounding box.south east)
               --cycle;}},
    innerRectangle/.default=5mm%<- when called without parameter
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[outerRectangle, innerRectangle] (x) {\lipsum[1]};
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Screenshot of the box the update produces:

[image]

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27893/.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `path picture` option to add an inner filled region to your node:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzset{
    every node/.style={fill=blue!30,draw,rectangle,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt},
    outerRectangle/.style={fill=red!50,minimum height=3cm, minimum width=2.5cm},
    innerRectangle/.style={%
        path picture={%
            \draw[fill=blue!30] ([yshift=-#1]path picture bounding box.north east)
                -|([xshift=#1]path picture bounding box.west)
               |-([yshift=#1]path picture bounding box.south east)
               --cycle;}},
    innerRectangle/.default=3mm
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[outerRectangle] (o) {A};

        \node[outerRectangle,anchor=east, 
        innerRectangle=5mm, right=of o] (o1) {ABC};

        \node[outerRectangle, innerRectangle=2mm, below= of o] (o2) {text};

        \node[outerRectangle,anchor=east, innerRectangle, right=of o2] (o3) {12345};
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{document}
```

[image]

**Update:**

This is an alternative solution which I hope solves the problem of which area to use for text. Previous solution used a node over which an `inner border` was drawn. In this case an `inner node` is used for text and an extra path is added  as outer border. This outer border is defined with a `fit` node. Although this outer node has its own name for reference I don't know how to use it for positioning, so the positioning is only done with inner node.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{fit, positioning}

\tikzset{
    myborder/.style={%
        append after command={%
            \pgfextra
                \node[fit={([yshift=-#1]\tikzlastnode.south east) 
                ([shift={(-#1,#1)}]\tikzlastnode.north west)}, 
                fill=red!30, draw, inner sep=0pt]  (\tikzlastnode-b) {};\endpgfextra}},
    myborder/.default=3mm
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw, fill=blue!30, text width=4cm,
        myborder] (A) {\lipsum[2]};

    \node[draw, fill=green!30,
        myborder=2mm, right= 0pt of A] (B) {ABC};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I just stumbled across a problem: If I replace example text, e.g. `12345` by `\lipsum[1]` the outer (red) box is filled. I don't wanted the sep-area to get filled - do you have an Idea how to just fill the blue rectangle?

Comment: I've updated the answer, although it still show some problems related with positioning this kind of nodes, it solves the problem regarding text.