# How not to overlay the label and the text of a node

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I want the label of a node to be included in the node, I use for that
label = {[below]: label} but if I do that, the text of the node is written above the label. How to make the contents of the node start only under the label.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \node[text width=6em,draw,label={[below,draw]:label}] 
 { un texte un peu long sur plusieurs lignes};
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you need to use `TikZ` you can do a command (or `pic`). Two different nodes inside a `fit` one.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit}

\newcommand{\mynode}[2]{%
 \node[text width=6em, outer sep=0pt] (a) 
 {#2};
 \node[draw, above=0pt of a, outer sep=0pt] (b) 
 {#1};
 \node[fit=(a) (b), draw, inner sep=0pt]{};
}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \node[text width=6em,draw,label={[below,draw]:label}] 
 { un texte un peu long sur plusieurs lignes};
 \end{tikzpicture}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \mynode{label}{ un texte un peu long sur plusieurs lignes}
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you can accept `tcolorbox` a solution could be:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{
    title=#2,
    enhanced,
    sharp corners,
    size=small,
    colback=white,
    attach boxed title to top center={yshift*=-\tcboxedtitleheight},
    text width=6em,
    halign=flush left,
    coltitle=black,
    boxed title style={colback=white, sharp corners, size=small},
    #1
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{mybox}{label}
un texte un peu long sur plusieurs lignes
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: rpapa reminded me my own answer to [TikZ: How to define a node with a custom inner sep on one side (e.g. on the right side of an rectangle)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376065/tikz-how-to-define-a-node-with-a-custom-inner-sep-on-one-side-e-g-on-the-righ/376070#376070). Adapting it to the new scheme, it's possible to do something like:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit, positioning}

\tikzset{
    withlabel/.style={%
        append after command={%
            \pgfextra
                    \node[draw, anchor=south, outer sep=0pt] (\tikzlastnode-label) at (\tikzlastnode.north) {#1};
                \node[fit={(\tikzlastnode) (\tikzlastnode-label)}, 
                draw, inner sep=0pt]  (\tikzlastnode) {};\endpgfextra}}
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[text width=6em, withlabel={label a}] (a) {some long text which uses more than one line};

    \node[text width=8em, withlabel={label b}, right=of a] (b) {some long text which uses more than one line};

    \node[text width=10em, withlabel={label c}, below left=2cm and 1cm of b] (c) {some long text which uses more than one line};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it's already what I'm doing, but I'd prefer to keep the functioning of a node.  I want to be able to write\node[mynode,label={xxx}]{texte};

Comment: can we modify inner sep so that the larger difference is larger

Comment: @rpapa yes you can adjust `inner sep` to a larger value, but it's applied to four margins (`inner sep`) or to two margins (`inner {x|y}sep`). Therefore at least bottom margin will be as large as upper. Another solution could be to insert a vertical space before node's text.

Comment: only for the top, I have seen this answer
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376065/tikz-how-to-define-a-node-with-a-custom-inner-sep-on-one-side-e-g-on-the-righ/376070#376070, but I do not see how to use it

Comment: @rpapa with the update you can use a `node` syntax. Hope it's better now.

Comment: merci Ignasi, je valide

Comment: In fact, I would like several parts in the lower part.

Do you think I have to open a new question?

Comment: @rpapa To replace the regular node with a `rectangle split` is not a problem, but as the main node is not drawn, splitting lines are not drawn. You'll have to draw them later on.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to Ignasi's nice answer would be to simply make the node a bit larger with `minimum height` and shift the text by hand.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \node[text width=6em,draw,label={[below,draw]:label},minimum height=2.5cm,
 text depth=0.5cm] 
 { un texte un peu long sur plusieurs lignes};
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This approach comes with a shorter code but you need to adjust `minimum height` and `text depth` by hand.