# Tikz package different ysep for top and bottom

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

Is there a method to make a tikz node have different inner ysep for top and bottom?

It seems like there is no trivial option, but if someone can suggest a trick, it would be nice!

Comment: Welcome! This question seems to be related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27893. One thing you could do is to fit the node in another node in such a way that the inner sep becomes what you like it to be.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Thanks for your comment. I saw that question and tried that, but the problem was when I put some text on only one node, the height of the other node remains the same. I first created a node that serves as the outer line, and created other one which will contain some text in it.

Comment: The answer below does not have this problem, does it?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I think so, but can you make the name of each box different from its content? It's a little bit confusing what to put at fit=(A) or height("C").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome! Here are two ways of obtaining something like this. You could either use `fit` and shift the fitting node (nodes A and B), or play with `text height` and `text depth` (node C).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node[inner xsep=2pt,inner ysep=4pt,draw,anchor=base] at (-1,0) (Z){Z};
 \node[inner sep=0pt,draw,anchor=base] (A){A};
 \node[inner ysep=4pt,inner xsep=2pt,yshift=3pt,fit=(A),draw]{};
 \node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=base] at (1,0) (B){B}; 
 \node[inner ysep=4pt,inner xsep=2pt,yshift=3pt,fit=(B),draw]{};
 \node[inner xsep=2pt,inner ysep=0pt,text height={height("C")+7pt},text depth=1pt,draw,anchor=base] at (2,0) (C){C}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The inner frame for A is just to guide the eye.

One can make this more versatile by creating a style for that, `asymmetric fit`. The asymmetric fit will inherit the name from the node, and you can set the `upper ysep`, `lower ysep`, `left xsep` and `right xsep` as you wish with pgf keys. The initial values are `2pt`.

```
\tikzset{afit/aset={upper ysep=8pt,style={draw}}}
\path node[asymmetric fit] (node0){Z};
```

[image]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\tikzset{asymmetric fit/.style={inner sep=0pt,append after command={
 node[fit=(\tikzlastnode),afit/node style,outer sep=0pt,
    inner ysep=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/afit/upper ysep}/2+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/afit/lower ysep}/2,
    inner xsep=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/afit/left xsep}/2+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/afit/right xsep}/2,
    yshift=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/afit/upper ysep}/2-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/afit/lower ysep}/2,
    xshift=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/afit/left xsep}/2-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/afit/right xsep}/2,
        ](\tikzlastnode){}
}},
afit/.cd,upper ysep/.initial=2pt,lower ysep/.initial=2pt,
left xsep/.initial=2pt,right xsep/.initial=2pt,node style/.style={},
style/.code=\tikzset{afit/node style/.style={#1}},
aset/.code=\tikzset{afit/.cd,#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \tikzset{afit/aset={upper ysep=8pt,style={draw}}}
 \path node[asymmetric fit] (node0){Z};
 \draw[red] (node0.north east) -- ++ (1,0) -- (node0.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If you are tempted to simplify this using `\pgfextra`: please don't, this can have uncontrollable side effects.

Of course you can give the nodes different names.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node[inner xsep=2pt,inner ysep=4pt,draw,anchor=base] at (-1,0) (node0){Z};
 \node[inner sep=0pt,draw,anchor=base] (node1){A};
 \node[inner ysep=4pt,inner xsep=2pt,yshift=3pt,fit=(node1),draw] (node2) {};
 \node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=base] at (1,0) (node3){B}; 
 \node[inner ysep=4pt,inner xsep=2pt,yshift=3pt,fit=(node3),draw] (node4) {};
 \node[inner xsep=2pt,inner ysep=0pt,text height={height("C")+7pt},text depth=1pt,draw,anchor=base] at (2,0) (node5){C}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

An another trick may be use of node's `label`:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
box/.style = {draw, minimum size=7mm}
                        ]
\node[box]    {A};
\node[box, label={[anchor=north]above:B}] at (1,0)   {};
\node[box, label={[anchor=south]below:C}] at (2,0)   {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ... yet it does not adjust its size to the size of the contents of the node.